# Is it legal to run windows on a mac?

Tags: windows, macos, multi-boot, legal

I understand that it is Illegal to run OSx on a windows machine or PC for that matter, but is it illegal to do the reverse? Why or why not?

Comment: Do you have an Apple reference saying it's "illegal" for osx on a pc? Or even just against the TOS?

Comment: #IANAL but: It's not **illegal**, it *could* be a breach of contract with Apple, but no country in the world has a statute on their books making it a *crime* to run Mac OS on 3rd party hardware. Civil versus Criminal law.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Far from being 'illegal', Apple actively encourage users to run Windows on their machines as well as OSX. They've even created software called Bootcamp to make it easier to do so.

http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201258

So running Windows (or linux or whatever) on your Apple hardware is not illegal, it's not even a breach of the EULA.

Comment: Caveat! You must have a legal Windows OS license. Otherwise, you are pirating. Apple did not want to disappear entirely, so they've never licensed their OS to run under any form of emulator on Windows, and specifically forbid it. These days, it isn't a worry for them, but just a few years ago, that could have spelt the end of their hardware line (which is why they refuse to allow it).